# How to avoid to adding some characters when adding a new item in JSON with Java Script

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to add a new item to JSON with the following code ;

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsoncontent);
        
obj["subnets"]["values"].push('{"gateway": "2.2.2.2","prefixLength": 24,"dnsSuffix": null,"dnsServer1": "","dnsServer2": "","ipRanges":.... .bla bla bla');
    
Alert(JSON.stringify(obj,null,'\t'));
```

But, as you can see at below, new items is adding with "" and "\" characters. How can I avoid this ?

```
{
    "gateway": "1.1.1.1",
    "prefixLength": 24,
    "dnsSuffix": null,
    "dnsServer1": "",
    "dnsServer2": "",
    "ipRanges": {
        "values": []
    },
    "enabled": false,
    "totalIpCount": 0,
    "usedIpCount": null,
    "primaryIp": null,
    "autoAllocateIpRanges": false
},
"{  \"gateway\": \"2.2.2.2\",  \"prefixLength\": 24,  \"dnsSuffix\": null,  \"dnsServer1\": \"\",  \"dnsServer2\": \"\",  \"ipRanges\": {    \"values\": []  },  \"enabled\": false,  \"totalIpCount\": 0,  \"usedIpCount\": null,  \"primaryIp\": null,  \"autoAllocateIpRanges\": false}"
```

Comment: Well you are appending a string, so all the double quotes are [escaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) for you. Just remove the single quotes in line 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your push function, you append a string instead of an object. Try to remove quotes around this object.

```
obj["subnets"]["values"].push({"gateway": "2.2.2.2","prefixLength": 24,"dnsSuffix": null,"dnsServer1": "","dnsServer2": ""});
```